# How to resolve the duplicate error during interpolation

Tags: interpolation

I have few hundred data points corresponding to an irregular shape closed curve. As the result I have data points that have the same value of y but different values of x. I want to create an interpolation curve and find the intersection of the curve with a straight line. When I try to interpolate the data *Mathematica* tells me that there are duplicates. Is there any way of finding the intersection of the curve with a straight line?

Here is how I was trying to do it

```
aa = Interpolation[Data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Interpolation::inddp: "The point -6.72 in dimension 1 is duplicated"

FindRoot[aa[x] - x, {x, bestguess}]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that there are points with the same $x$ value but different $y$ values?  That will cause errors.  Having the same $y$ value but different $x$ values will not cause errors.  Why interpolation would work in the first case is quite clear.  You would need to decide what to do (how to interpolate) in those points and describe that in the question.  Then people can advise you on how to implement your idea.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do it with Interpolation and FindRoot. Note that using `Interpolation[]` this way (one coordinate at a time) you'll not get the "duplicate point" error message:

```
SeedRandom[42];
len = 200;
lineParms = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2];
list = Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, len]}];
curve = FindCurvePath[list];
{xc, yc} = Interpolation[#, PeriodicInterpolation->True]&/@ Transpose@list[[First@curve]];
myline[x_, y_] := y + #1 x + #2 & @@ lineParms;
fr = First@FindRoot[myline[xc[t], yc[t]], {t, len}]
{xc[t], yc[t]} /. fr
(*
t -> 189.04
{-0.997462, 0.0701403}
*)
```

Showing the intersection:

```
GraphicsRow[{
    Plot[myline[xc[t], yc[t]], {t, 1, 2 (len + 1)}, 
         Epilog -> {Red, PointSize@Large, Point@({t, myline[xc[t], yc[t]]} /. fr)}], 
    Show[
         ContourPlot[myline[x, y] == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}], 
         ParametricPlot[{xc[t], yc[t]}, {t, 1, (len + 1)}], 
         Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point@({xc[t], yc[t]} /. fr)}]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I guess FindCurvePath is the key here. Very nice.

Comment: @RahulNarain The only caveat is that `FindCurvePath[]` isn't very clever. I've had to roll up my own in some not-so-special cases

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you want, but perhaps useful as an approximation:

```
list = Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, 100]}];
curve = FindCurvePath[list];
myPoly = Polygon@list[[curve[[1]]]];
myLine = Line@{{-1, -1}, {-.5, 1}};
pts = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[{myLine, myPoly}];
Graphics[{Blue, FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], myPoly, 
         Green, Thickness[.02], myLine, 
         Red, PointSize[.05], Point@pts}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]